# How can i backtrace my modernizr to find what all the custom download includes?

Tags: modernizr

I have 2 programs that require the 'modernizr' base plugin.

The first plugin includes:  modernizr.custom.17475.js

The second plugin includes: modernizr.custom.87626.js

they are the minified versions and i cant figure out what all they include because i dont want to load the same features twice on my site.

How can i backtrace these to get a list of what they include?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the time the minified builds include the custom url that created the build (eg, something like http://modernizr.com/download/#-csstransforms-csstransitions-touch-shiv-cssclasses-prefixed-teststyles-testprop-testallprops-prefixes-domprefixes-load). Each one of the words between the `-`'s is a separate test.

If that was stripped, you could just run each script in the browser, then compare the Modernizr objects that are created.